# Recover an essential infimum given a family of measures from a process,

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, supremum-and-infimum

Suposse that for some family of probability measures $\mathcal{P}$ the process $ess\inf_{\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{P}}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}[B|\mathcal{F_t}]$ is a submartingale, for some possitive r.v. $B$. My question is for any possitive submartingale $Y$ is possible to find a r.v. $B$ such that $Y_t=ess\inf_{\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{P}}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}[B|\mathbb{F_t}]$. For example if the family has some estructure?

Comment: When you use "submartingale" do you mean "$\Bbb P$-submartingale for each $\Bbb P\in\mathcal P$"? Or "$\Bbb P$-submartingale for some specific $\Bbb P_0$"?

Comment: As you said. It is a $\mathbb{P}$ for eache $\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{P}$. I apologize for not specifying.